# Can't watch livestream from RTMP HLS server with IPv6 on iOS app

Tags: ios, dns, ipv6, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I can perfectly watch the stream from my iOS application if my ip is an IPv4.
If I have an IPv6, impossible.

**RTMP side**

For my RTMP server, I use the protocol HLS and HTTPS. I have compiled it with --with-ipv6 and I set the port 443 for ipv4/6 on my nginx.conf :

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443;
        server_name stream.ma-loon.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.ma-loon.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.ma-loon.com/privkey.pem;
```

[my port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIpKh.png)

**IOS Side**

```
func playTrendingVid(link: String) {

    if !link.isEmpty || link != "nil" || link != ".m3u8"{

        let videoURL = URL(string: link)
        let dummyUrl = URL(string:"sdkjcsdc4")
        let player = AVPlayer(url:videoURL ?? dummyUrl!)
        print("player URL")
        print(videoURL)
        playerViewController.player = player
        playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = true
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            self.playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    }
```

**DNS & Domaine side**

The ipv6 is well activated on my server.
I use Yunohost for my SSL and I have configured my DNS from IONOS panel:
I stream on my subdomain.
[My redirection for my domain ma-loon.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmpGt.png)
[My redirection for subdomain stream.ma-loon.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE9SG.png)

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

My problem come from my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name stream.ma-loon.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.ma-loon.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.ma-loon.com/privkey.pem;
```

I have forgot ssl for ipv6 like here

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name stream.ma-loon.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.ma-loon.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.ma-loon.com/privkey.pem;
```